# What is wrong with my Javascript Mobile Menu?

Tags: javascript

I am having a difficult time finding out what's wrong with my mobile menu. I only want the menu items to show up when I press the button in mobile. Please view the URL on any mobile device.

URL: [www.patrickmmangan.com/employment](http://www.patrickmmangan.com/employment)

Relevant JS:

```
function menuBar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("links");
    if (x.style.display === "inline-block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-block";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question, without it we can't be of much help.

Comment: The problem is that `x.style.display === "inline-block"` isn't true when the menuBar button is clicked for the first time, so the menu is set to `inline-block` first, then hides when you click a second time. A div's default `display` value is `block`, but even if you make that change, that won't fix the code. You would need to use `getComputedStyle()`. The quick fix is to reverse the check in the code. Simply check if `x.style.display === "none"` and swap the `x.style.display` assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this,just initialize the display style first

```
<div id="links" style="display: none;">
```